# What Stops the Windings on an Electric motor From Shorting with Each Other?

Tags: motor, insulation

What stops the windings from shorting with each other? Are the windings insulated when the copper is still not bent, then the insulated copper is bent into the winding shape?

Comment: OK, Comment withdrawn. Took me a while to find any specification of the breakdown voltage for the insulation on magnet wire. Most people who sell the stuff just cite which international standard(s) they comply with—totally different from "hook-up" wire, where everybody says up-front what voltage it's rated for-but eventually, I did find a table, and lets just say, I was surprised by how high the numbers were.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I have never looked it up but I have seen 240 VAC motor windings and the way the wires are led into the junction box for connection with normal insulated wire. So I knew the insulation rating had to be high enough for 240 VAC + margin. Also, for some "inverter rated" induction motors, the insulation has to hold up to even higher voltages due to transients inherent in inverter drive.

Comment: If either of the answers is satisfactory, perhaps you could officially accept one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wire used for winding electric motors (i.e. brushless motors), called "magnet wire" or "enameled copper wire" is covered in a non-conductive substance before being wound into coils.

According to this datasheet from [Remington Industries](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/RemingtonInd/PolyurethaneMagnetWireDataSheet.pdf), this insulating material is polyurethane, with an optional polyamide coating for extra protection.

Answer (score 0):

Magnet wire is used which is uses a thin enamel insulating layer.